# TabHost HomeUp Button

Tags: android, android-tabhost, back-button

I have a TabHost with 5 fragments. One of the Fragments leads to an Activity. When I press the back button in that activity it will lead me back to the fragment that started the activity, however if I press the home-up button in the actionbar it leads me back to the first tab's fragment. How can I make it go back to the fragment that called like the back button does when I press the home up button?

Answer (score 0):

you need to override the action for the home button

in your activity -

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

this should cause the 2 behaviors (back button and home up) to be identical

Comment: this exhibits the same behavior as I described. There is no difference.

Comment: you're gonna need to post some code to get some more specific help.  Preferably the calling fragment and the activity it opens.